# Not able to install plex media server on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, plex

I have problems with installing the plex media server on Ubuntu 16.04 (i386).

This is what I get when I run the `plexmediaserver.service`:

```
● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since sø. 2017-07-23 21:47:12 CEST; 19s ago
  Process: 2015 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/m

juli 23 21:47:07 Lidarende-Ubuntu systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
juli 23 21:47:12 Lidarende-Ubuntu systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling res
juli 23 21:47:12 Lidarende-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
juli 23 21:47:12 Lidarende-Ubuntu systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
juli 23 21:47:12 Lidarende-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
```

This is what I did to install it:

```
echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plexmediaserver -y
```

Comment: This seems to happen with the 32-bit version of `plexmediaserver` but not the 64-bit version, and I'm not sure why.